# Mimic prod environment on CI server

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, travis-ci, circleci, codeship

I have to setup `CI/CD` for my organisation.

My requirement is that `ci-sever` (whether hosted or on-premise ) should mimic the prod environment like `operating system` , `/var/log` directories , `nginx` , `php-fpm` configuration so on. It gives us more confidence when running integration test cases.

As we setup `jenkins` on-premise server so we can easily replicate the prod environment on `jenkins`server.

How can I do that with any `ci` hosting service like `travis-ci` , 'codeship' , 'circle-ci' etc ??

Comment: Just how you'd do it normally.

Answer (score 0):

1. Operating system
   If you use ubuntu 12.04/14.04 then most commercial offering (travis, cicrcle ci, I think codeship also) are already using it so you're ok there. If not then I believe you'll need to use docker to setup a container with the expected operating system

2.software packages and other configuration

All commercial offering support specifying the system packages you need and installing on build (Usually with cached, so quicker then usual install). Of course if you are using a docker container you can pre bake it with all the packages you need.

Same go for /var/log just run a script in "pre" step of the build and setup whatever you need and expect

3. Bonus points
   The best way to handle production infrastructure is automation so if you automate your infrastructure setup with configuration management tool (ansible is my favorite, other popular options are salt, chef, puppet, engineCf) and then use the same script to prepare the environment in your build jobs..